# com.amazonaws.AmazonServiceException: Query key condition not supported

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I am fetching data from AWS DynamoDB Table. With the below code, I can fetch single item from table with this code.

```
    Condition hashKeyCondition = new Condition()
            .withComparisonOperator(ComparisonOperator.GE.toString())
            .withAttributeValueList(new AttributeValue().withN("1"));

    Map<String, Condition> keyConditions = new HashMap<String, Condition>();
    keyConditions.put("ID", hashKeyCondition);

    Map<String, AttributeValue> lastEvaluatedKey = null;

    do
    {
        QueryRequest queryRequest = new QueryRequest()
                .withTableName("TABLE_NAME")
                .withKeyConditions(keyConditions)
                .withExclusiveStartKey(lastEvaluatedKey);

        QueryResult queryResult = dynamoDBClient.query(queryRequest);

        for (Map<String, AttributeValue> item : queryResult.getItems())
        {
            String value = item.get("column_name").getS();
            Log.i("MainActivity", value);
        }

        lastEvaluatedKey = queryResult.getLastEvaluatedKey();

    } while (lastEvaluatedKey != null);
```

But I am trying to fetch all the items that are greater than ID = "1". So I changed the `ComparisonOperator.GE` to `ComparisonOperator.GT`. Below is the following code.

```
Condition hashKeyCondition = new Condition()
    .withComparisonOperator(ComparisonOperator.GT.toString())
    .withAttributeValueList(new AttributeValue().withN("1"));

Map<String, Condition> keyConditions = new HashMap<String, Condition>();
keyConditions.put("ID", hashKeyCondition);

Map<String, AttributeValue> lastEvaluatedKey = null;

do
{
    QueryRequest queryRequest = new QueryRequest()
            .withTableName("TABLE_NAME")
            .withKeyConditions(keyConditions)
            .withConsistentRead(true)
            .withExclusiveStartKey(lastEvaluatedKey);

    QueryResult queryResult = dynamoDBClient.query(queryRequest);

    for (Map<String, AttributeValue> item : queryResult.getItems())
    {
        String value = item.get("column_name").getS();
        Log.i("MainActivity", value);
    }

    lastEvaluatedKey = queryResult.getLastEvaluatedKey();

} while (lastEvaluatedKey != null);
```

**But I am getting AmazonServiceException**
`com.amazonaws.AmazonServiceException: Query key condition not supported (Service: AmazonDynamoDBv2; Status Code: 400; Error Code: ValidationException; Request ID: XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX`.

Please Help.

Answer (score 3):

I'm a bit surprised the first piece of code works, but it might be a product of the SDK in use. You can only use equals (EQ) when querying the primary key (hash). You can use the other operators when the query includes a condition that checks against the sort key (range).

"The selection criteria for the query. For a query on a table, you can have conditions only on the table primary key attributes. You must provide the partition key name and value as an EQ condition. You can optionally provide a second condition, referring to the sort key."

Source: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_Query.html

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that this would be an error in the data schema of the table. If you don't have a range key established for Id you may not be able to sort on it. I believe the answer to your problem is located in this document.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/QueryingJavaDocumentAPI.html

Specifically the statement below stands out:

> > Specifying Optional Parameters
>
> The query method supports several optional parameters. For example,
>   you can optionally narrow the results from the preceding query to
>   return replies in the past two weeks by specifying a condition. The
>   condition is called a sort key condition, because DynamoDB evaluates
>   the query condition that you specify against the sort key of the
>   primary key. You can specify other optional parameters to retrieve
>   only a specific list of attributes from items in the query result.

Maybe try adding a range key or secondary index and see if that would support your id query?